# How can I create a second root user on Kali Linux whose file contents cannot be viewed by the system admin?

Tags: kali-linux, root

I have 2 users on my Kali machine. One is `root`, the other is not. How can I change the second user to root so that the main root account cannot view the file contents of the other?

Update: I have played around with the File System a bit, and have managed to block the the second user's "home" file from view of the root user. I adjusted the permissions in a few areas so that now, the root user can see the files/folders of the non-root user, but cannot open them. (In regard to keyloggers and other tools, I am also the root user, so it doesn't really matter from that aspect). I will just add the non-root user to the sudo list so that I have a little more flexibility.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: root has  access to all files.

Comment: This... doesn't make much sense, I'm afraid. There is only one root, there cannot be many. You can of course use `sudo`, but I assume you know this since you are using Kali. So please [edit] your question and explain what you need in more detail and why the standard approaches don't work for you. Given that [Kali is not a regular operating system and should not be used as a regular operating system](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/), I am assuming that you are an expert and know how to set this sort of thing up which makes this question even more confusing.

Comment: Encryption might save you but considering that both accounts are root, they can do anything with the system including bad things like installing keyloggers or rootkits.

Comment: Could constrain the root user via SELinux policy and set a custom type for the "protected" folder, but at some point some user is going to have to be able to run unconfined (or with secadm type user)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have two `root` accounts on a Linux system. Well, you can by assigning both of them UID 0, but they'll be the same account, really.

Second, even if you could, the `root` user has read and write access - by definition - to everything. So you can't hide anything from the root user.

As pointed out in the comments, the second user *could* try to protect their files via encryption but `root` can easily thwart that by creating a fake wrapper script around the encryption binary, run a keylogger, etc.

Comment: they won't be the same account in all senses, you can still have two different login names with two different home directories and two different sets of configuration files. Of course all their files will be owned by UID 0, but that doesn't matter since the root users won't be subject to regular filesystem access controls anyway.